# Memsic Accelerometer not returning T value

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer

I hooked up a Memsic2125 accelerometer to a Arduino Uno.  X and Y values are returning fine, but the T value is returning -4000 every time.

```
// these constants won't change:
const int xPin = 2;     // X output of the accelerometer
const int yPin = 3;     // Y output of the accelerometer
const int tPin = 4;     // Y output of the accelerometer

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the pins connected to the accelerometer
  // as inputs:
  pinMode(xPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(yPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(tPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // variables to read the pulse widths:
  int pulseX, pulseY, pulseT;
  // variables to contain the resulting accelerations
  int accelerationX, accelerationY, accelerationT;

  // read pulse from x- and y-axes:
  pulseX = pulseIn(xPin,HIGH);  
  pulseY = pulseIn(yPin,HIGH);
  pulseT = pulseIn(tPin,HIGH);
  // convert the pulse width into acceleration
  // accelerationX and accelerationY are in milli-g's: 
  // earth's gravity is 1000 milli-g's, or 1g.
  accelerationX = ((pulseX / 10) - 500) * 8;
  accelerationY = ((pulseY / 10) - 500) * 8;
  accelerationT = ((pulseT / 10) - 500) * 8;

  // print the acceleration
  Serial.print(accelerationX);
  // print a tab character:
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accelerationY);
  // print a tab character:
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accelerationT);
  Serial.println();

  delay(100);
}
```

The output looks like this...

-104    -24 -4000
-96 -24 -4000
-96 -24 -4000
-104    -24 -4000
-96 -24 -4000
-104    -24 -4000
40  -216    -4000
120 -184    -4000
72  -200    -4000
-80 -376    -4000
456 672 -4000
-8  -40 -4000
-112    0   -4000
-112    0   -4000

Any ideas on how to get the -4000 fixed?

Comment: Maybe I 'm wrong but it seems that only two accelerations (X, Y) are digital. What is T standing for?

Comment: According to the datasheet, T is the chip temperature and is an analog value, not a digital pulse like X and Y accelerations, hence you cannot read it and compute it the same way as X and Y!